# Submit button not submitting

Tags: php, html, css, submit

```
<div class = 'buttons'>
 <button type="submit" class="regular" name="save">
        <img src="elephant.png" alt=""/>
        Memory
 </button>
</div>
```

This is the code for a submit button

however when i try validate the form using php, the button does not seem to be submitting

```
<?php if( isset($_POST['save']) && $_POST['save'])
{
$submit = $_POST['save'];
echo "lol";
}
else
{
echo "lola";

}
```

Comment: are you sure that you do not need a form which to submit ?

Comment: You should include your code within `<form method="post" action="path/to/your/php/processing/file">` and </form> tags

Comment: yes i have a form method = post

Comment: What do you mean by "It's not working"? What exactly is it or isn't it doing?

Comment: you getting output as `lola` or blank?

Comment: Post the entire form, please.

Comment: That means `$_POST['save']` is not set. Show all the code in your form

Comment: <form method = 'POST'>
<textarea name="styled-textarea" id="styled" ></textarea>
<br>
<div class = 'buttons'>
 <button type="submit" class="regular" name="save">
        <img src="elephant.png" alt=""/>
       Memory
    </button>
 </div>
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written already your code lacks the  wrapping. While submit button as a button might work without the form, then catching the _POST data surely doesnt.

Also, your solution for image-button could be better, maybe something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input[type="submit"] {background: url('elephant.png') right no-repeat; padding: 10px; padding-left: 30px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;} /* or call this .regular */
</style>
<?
if ($_POST['save']) { // the trigger
    echo '<h1>Cooking with fire now!</h1>';
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Memory" class="regular" />
    </div>
</form>
```

- Note that `class = "buttons"` with the spaces, is incorrect syntax!

Comment: That is going to return Notice errors if the form hasn't been submitted yet.

Comment: Not in normal error reporting mode, since OP didn't specific the error reporting level, your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: Just FYI: you need to escape the `<form>` tag in your answer, because it doesn't show up otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Submit buttons only work in forms. Try to wrap the whole thing in a `form` tag and try again.

Comment: you don't need the second conditional check then. all you need is `if( isset($_POST['save'])`

Answer (score 1):

Your submit button doesn't have any value to send when posting the form. **The `<button>` element *does not* send its element's content as its submit value.** You still have to add a `value` attribute to the element in order for it to *have* a submitted value. Since you don't, it's sending an empty string, which is causing your conditional statement to fail:

```
if( isset($_POST['save']) && $_POST['save'])
```

Since `$_POST['save']` is empty, that second part returns false and thus it goes to your `else` block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that you want:

```
<form name="myForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<div class="buttons">
 <button type="submit" class="regular" name="save" value="Save">
        <img src="elephant.png" alt="Elephant" />
        Memory
 </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

- You should include your code within `<form method="post" action="path/to/your/php/processing/file">` and `</form>` tags
- Replace your button code with `<input type="submit" class="regular" name="save" />`
- Remove `isset($_POST['save']) &&` part from condition of if as you don't have set `value` for your button.