# My if(isset($_POST["submit"])) is returning false and I cannot figure out why

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo out the values of radio inputs the user has clicked, but my if(isset($_POST["submit"])) keeps returning false, so my code wont execute. I cannot put my entire html code on here because it is too big, but here is the copy/pasted form and action attributes:

```
<form class="cooper-form" action="includes/tasks.inc.php" method="post" name="cooper_form" id="cooper_form">
```

And here is the code for the submit button that ISSET is supposed to be checking for:

```
<button id="input_2" class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" > Submit Service Form </button>
```

This is tasks.inc.php:

```
<?php


require_once 'form_functions.inc.php';
require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {    
    $cylinderhead=$_POST["cylinder_head"];
    $fuelvalves=$_POST["fuel_valves"];
    $airstartvalve=$_POST["air_start_valve"];
    $jetcellbody=$_POST["jet_cell_body"];
    $rockerarmshafts=$_POST["rocker_arm_shafts"];
    $valveadjusters=$_POST["valve_adjusters"];

    

    defineScope($cylinderhead,$fuelvalves,$airstartvalve,$jetcellbody,$rockerarmshafts,$valveadjusters);
}
```

All the different values you see referenced above are the values I put in for each radio input, and all the names match their name in the html form, so that is not the issue.

Below is the code for the function defineScope(), which is in the file form_functions.inc.php:

```
function defineScope($cylinderhead,$fuelvalves,$airstartvalve,$jetcellbody,$rockerarmshafts,$valveadjusters){
    $tasklist=array($cylinderhead,$fuelvalves,$airstartvalve,$jetcellbody,$rockerarmshafts,$valveadjusters);
    $arrlength=count($tasklist);
    for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++){
        echo ".$tasklist[$x].";
        echo "<br>";
}
```

I tried to do some troubleshooting to figure out why the page keeps coming up as blank and I am 99% sure it is the ISSET statement. The url shows that after clicking the submit button, I am correctly navigated to tasks.inc.php with error=none, and if I put an echo statement outside the ISSET statement in tasks.inc.php, it spits it out on the page. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Add `var_dump($_POST);` at the top of tasks.inc.php and show your output. Is the button inside the form? Is there any script involved in submitting the form? Do your included php files touch `$_POST`?

Comment: You added the javascript tag but do not show any javascript. You should add any relevant javascript, or remove the tag if there is none. You also have the sql tag which does not appear to pertain to your problem in any way, you should remove that tag.

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743326/2943403).  If this does not resolve your problem [edit] your question to show your coding improvement and diagnostic details and maybe we can find a better duplicate.